# How do I use timestamps from Excel for source block arrival dates?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am trying to use an Excel spreadsheet with a timestamp in the format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" as arrival dates for my agents that are generated within a source block. However, when I change the format of the timestamp from "String" to "Date", all of the timestamps are converted to blanks. Not really sure why this is happening, any help is appreciated!

ACE

Comment: it will be helpful if you add some code, otherwise, you can check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion

Answer (score 0):

None of the arrival dates of the agents were within the selected time frame to run the simulation, which is why I was seeing no agents being generated from the source block. I could not post code as this was not an issue with code, but rather with the simulation options. I resolved this with the following steps:

1. Click on Simulation:Main
2. Select Stop at specified date from the Stop drop-down
3. Choose both the Start date and the Stop date for the simulation experiment (note: if you are using actual arrival dates for the agents you need to ensure the simulation time frame includes the arrival dates!)

This was a silly mistake of mine, but I hope this helps someone else in the future!